# d3.js force-directed issues, significance of "d"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a something to work with D3.js. Namely, I'm trying to make a tree of nodes, using the basic code from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021953.

[image]

I switched it to load the data inline, as opposed to loading from file, because I'm using it with a Rails application and don't want to have repetitive information. I switched the line so that you could see the format of my data.

Anyways, here's the bulk of my code:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var nodes = [{"title":"Duncan's Death","id":"265"},{"title":"Nature Thrown Off","id":"266"},{"title":"Cows Dead","id":"267"},{"title":"Weather Bad","id":"268"},{"title":"Lighting kills man","id":"269"},{"title":"Macbeth's Rise","id":"270"}];
  var links = [{"source":"265","target":"266","weight":"1"},{"source":"266","target":"267","weight":"1"},{"source":"266","target":"268","weight":"1"},{"source":"268","target":"269","weight":"1"}];

  var firstelement = +links[0].source;

  links.forEach(function(l) {
    l.source = +l.source;
    l.source = l.source-firstelement;
    l.target = +l.target
    l.target = l.target-firstelement;
    });

  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .charge(-1000)
      .linkDistance(300)
      .size([width, height]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.weight); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circle_node")
      .attr("r", 50)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); })

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

  node.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; } )
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("x", function(a) { return a.x; })
        .attr("y", function(a) { return a.y; }); 
  });

<% end %>
```

This seems like it should work to me, but I can seem to manage it. The links work, but the nodes all remain in the top left corner. I've tried just entering the circles directly and appending the text to them (staying close to the source code I listed above,) but while the circles behave properly, it doesn't display the text. I'd like the title to be centered in the nodes.

More generally, I'm kind of confused by how this is working. What does "d" refer to within lines like

```
function(d) { return d.source.x; }
```

It seems to be declaring a function and calling it simultaneously. I know that it doesn't have to be specifically the character "d," (for instance, switching the "d" to an "a" seems to make no difference as long as it's done both in the declaration and within the function.) But what is it referring to? The data entered into the object that's being modified? For instance, if I wanted to print that out, (outside of the attribute,) how would I do it?

Sorry, I'm new to D3 (and fairly new to JavaScript in general,) so I have a feeling the answer is obvious, but I've been looking it up and through tutorials and I'm still lost. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a simple problem with your code that is causing all your nodes to stay in the top left corner. You are trying to position each node using the code:

```
node.attr("x", function(a) { return a.x; })
    .attr("y", function(a) { return a.y; });
```

However, `node` is a selection of `g`s *which do not take `x` and `y` attributes*. Instead, you can move each `node` using translate transform, e.g.

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Making this change should allow the nodes to move around.

---

Next, moving to your question about "d", I think the first thing you need to understand is what you can do with a selection of elements in D3. From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections): a selection (such as `nodes`) "is an array of elements pulled from the current document." Once you have a selection of elements, you can apply operators to change the attributes or style of the elements. You can also *bind data* to each element.

In your case, you are binding data to a selection of `g`s (nodes):

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
```

You are then using [`attr`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-attr) to change the position of each node. However, instead of setting the `x` and `y` attributes of each element to the same value, you are passing `attr` an [anonymous function](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions) that will return a (presumably different) position for each node:

```
node.attr("x", function(a) { return a.x; })
    .attr("y", function(a) { return a.y; });
```

This behavior is also explained in the docs for `attr`:

> Attribute values and such are specified as either constants or
>   functions; the latter are evaluated for each element.

Thus, `d` represents an individual element (Object) in `nodes`.

So going back to your code, on each tick two things are happening:

1. The position of each node (data) is being recalculated by `force`.
2. Each corresponding element is then being moved to its new location by the anonymous function you pass to `force.on`.

Comment: If it helps clarify; my impression has been that `d` is supposed to stand for `datum`, as in an individual piece of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks, this helps significantly. Looks like I should study SVG's more. As far as my second question goes, so it will basically assume that whatever variable I choose (usually `d`, as that seems pretty standard) is an element of the collection that I'm doing things to (such as `node` when I'm calling `.attr`,) and the only reason that I'm calling a function there instead of just `.attr("x", d.x)` is that without the function it would try to evaluate `d.x` as a constant, and therefore not do it for each element individually?

Comment: @user3043447: yes, `attr("x", d.x)` would evaluate to the same value for each element in the selection. To be clear, this is true for any value, e.g. `attr("x", 20)` (I'm not sure where `d` is coming from in your example).